# Split alphanumeric characters in excel using python

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have a excel sheet containing lot of employee ids as shown below, the data contains only in 1st column

```
ALopp190 
ARaga789 
Lshastri921
DPatel592 
ANaidu026
```

When i run the python code i need output as shown below.

```
ALopp190     k190   190
ARaga789     k789   789
Lshastri921  k921   921
DPatel592    k592   592
ANaidu026    k026   026
```

Basically it has to split letters and digits and in 2nd column it should always start with k then corresponding number, While in 3rd Column i need only number. This is what i tried and i am not getting the desired output.

```
import xlrd 
loc = ("C:\\Users\\Kiran\\Desktop\\Emplyoees\\User.xlsx") 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

import re 
df = "User.xlsx"
res = [re.findall(r'(\w+?)(\d+)', df)[0] ]
```

Can you please guide me in fixing this issue.

Comment: why are you giving file name as input to `re.findall()`

Comment: Don't tag this 'spyder', it's just a simple Python regex question. (spyder is only an IDE, but that's irrelevant, this issue occurs no matter what IDE or console you run in, only tag it 'spyder' if the issue only occurs in spyder.)

Answer (score 2):

Using [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)
df.columns = ['id']
df['X'] = 'k' + df['id'].str.extract('(\d+)')
df['Y'] = df['id'].str.extract('(\d+)')

df.to_excel('result.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: I coded the answer and was just about to post the same answer. Cheers mate! :D

Comment: @komatiraju thanks for your code, When i run it i get error as "
KeyError: 'id'"

Comment: But there is no Column name in my excel sheet , since Row 1 is employee id and the pattern follows